# Log off as local "administrator" user, get blank login screen

Tags: windows-7, login, logoff

I have an imaged lab environment running Windows 7 and attached to a domain.

The local Administrator account is enabled for certain maintenance and prep tasks.

Every time I logoff from the local Administrator account, it brings me back to the standard Ctrl+Alt+Del login screen.  When I press that combination, all the user controls vanish except for the accessibility button down in the left hand corner.

The only way I can seem to escape from this is to tap the power button to initiate a shutdown.

Windows is up-to-date, and logging off as any other user operates normally.  The "hide last user" local security policy option is enabled.

Has anyone seen this phenomenon before and how can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this before it seems like a bug.
So my idea is that you can try some registry tweaks that will force the behavior and bring interface back.
for example you can try to bring the old classic User interface login here:
[How to Make Windows 7 Require a User Name and Password at Log On](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/61650-log-user-name-password.html)

Or check if the secure login interface is enabled here:
[Windows 7 - Secure Logon - Press CTRL + ALT + DELETE to log on](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/612-secure-logon-press-ctrl-alt-delete-log-2.html)

Hope that can help fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the `UserInit` value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`?  Normally, this will be simply `C:\Windows\system32\userinit.exe`, but other items might be there depending on your software. Regardless, make sure userinit.exe is in there and everything else in there is legit.

Also, check the `Shell` value in that same key (`Winlogon`). It should be simply `explorer.exe`. Some users have reported a null character after the `.exe`, which will cause issues. It might behoove you to delete this value and re-create it, if you're comfortable with that.